# Can download, can't read

Tags: android

I'm using this to download a file:

```
String url = "https://File To Download";
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setDescription("My File To Download");
    request.setTitle("Downloading");

    // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, context.getString(R.string.dloded_latest_numbers));

    // get download service and enqueue file
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
```

Which all works great. Puts the file in the standard Downloads directory which I confirm is there.

Then I try to read the file into a BufferedReader like so:

```
 File latestNumbersFile;
        latestNumbersFile = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, getString(R.string.dloded_latest_numbers));
        TextView displayArray = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentNumbers);
        String tmp = latestNumbersFile.toString(); // Converts type (File) to string type
        displayArray.setText(tmp);
        BufferedReader buffedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(latestNumbersFile));
```

Then display the file location in a TextView, which works and gives the dir /Download/File To Download
Note the leading "/" not sure if that's important...

My question is:
Using File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, getString(R.string.dloded_latest_numbers) allows me to download to a dir I expect the file to be in, but using the exact same reference to read the file from I get java.io.FileNotFoundException open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Can anyone help??

Comment: what are your app permissions?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok you have only asked for `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission but you dont have the permission to read from the SD Card. you also need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```